# Can I change my previous app name and use the original name for my new app?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app on app store. I want to publish a new app with the existing app name I know apple doesn’t allow that. So can I change my previous app name and use that original name for publishing my new app?

Let assume my previous app name is “abc”. Can I rename my previous app to “abcd” and use the name “abc” for my new app?

Comment: Unfortunately, this really is not a programming question, and thus is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this forum. You will need to direct this to some other forum. When you do that, perhaps you can clarify your question to specify whether you really need/want to keep that old app out there, and/or simply replace it (i.e., just do a new submission with the same name and same bundle identifier)…

Answer (score 0):

on https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/, applications are identified by their App ID.

You should get the App ID of the "old" app and configure it into the new app :

1. Xcode -> in project left navigation bar, select the name of your project
2. Select the target of you app
3. Select "Signing & Capabilities" tab
4. Update the field labeled "Bundle Identifier" with the value from your old app
5. Archive the app and publish it on App Store Connect

The old app would be totally overwritten by the new one.